# How to make this AJAX (login) request to be secured

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a login system to my website, but the browser says it is not secured: [the browser's message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb03C.jpg)

Heres is my html:

```
<div id="loginform">
      Bejelentkezés
      <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="email"></input>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Jelszó" id="password"></input>
      <button id="loginbutton">Bejelentkezés</button>
      <div id="errormsg"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is my Ajax:

```
 $("#loginbutton").click(function(){
          var user ={
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
          };

            $.ajax({
            url: 'login.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"user": JSON.stringify(user)},
            success: function(data){
              if(data.success){
                alert(data.user_id);
              }
              else{
                document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "A bejelentkezés sikertelen";
              }
            }
          });
         });
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "getpet");

 $results = array(
   'success' => false,
   'user_id' => "azaz",
   'fname' => "",
   'lname' => ""
 );
 if(isset($_POST['user'])){
    $user = json_decode($_POST['user']);
        $email = $user->email;
        $password = md5($user->password);
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";
        $rowsql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rowsql, MYSQLI_BOTH);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rowsql) == "1"){
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['fname'];
            $_SESSION['lname'] = $row['lname'];

      $results['success'] = true;
      $results['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
      $results['fname'] = $row['fname'];
      $results['lname'] = $row['lname'];
      }
    }
    else{
      $results['user_id']= "VAnbaj";
    }

            echo json_encode($results);
 ?>
```

It works, but i don't know how to make it safe.
I'd be glad if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to get rid of that warning message, you have to serve your site over https with a valid certificate.

Comment: So i should buy an SSL certificate?

Comment: I think that's the proper solution if you really want to protect your users/data. Maybe there's some trick, like renaming the input names or ids, changing the login url, encode your postdata with js on client side, but all of these are half solution. Moving your site to https has other advantages, like better SEO rating, access for using the browsers location API, more trust to your site from your users, etc... So my advice is definitely YES :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: These days, you don't have to pay for SSL certificates, you can get them for free at letsencrypt.org